# How can I chaining jQuery animate function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have two divisions and want to chain their animate function. But I have some logic in the first animate function callback to update the value and display it into the first division & it is working perfectly. The problem is when the animation of the first division is finished, the second division doesn't start. I've passed the second div animate function in the first's callback, nothing is happened.

**jQuery code:**

```
$('#jq').animate({marginTop:-250+'px',height:250+'px'},2000,'easeOutBack',function(e){

                var counter = 0;
                var height = $(this).height();
                counter+=height/50;
                $('#jq-rating').text(counter);
                //$(noid).append(counter);
            $('#wordpress').animate({marginTop:-250+'px',height:250+'px'},2000,'easeOutBack',function(e){

                var counter = 0;
                var height = $(this).height();
                counter+=height/50;
                $('#wp-rating').text(counter);
                //$(noid).append(counter);

       });


       });
```

[My JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketjack/LSE8w/12/)

Comment: pro tip: you dont need to add units to the animation if you just use ({marginTop: -250, height: 250})

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, but you are not able to see because both the divs are overlapping to each other.

add this css:

```
#wordpress{
    margin-left:60px
}
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/LSE8w/13/

Comment: Thank you so much Ashish for your quick response. Now its working. You save my day.

Comment: I am really glad that it helped you. Cheers!